# Arithmetic combination of multiple rows into one row - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently working with oracle SQL with a database with different metrics. However, what I'm looking for is an arithmetic combination of the different metrics. All of this information is currently in one table.

Ideally I would create a new metric through basic math of currently stored data. I would not need any of the current output, just it's combination into the new metric.

I don't know how to limit it to know that for each specific building/date to only combine metric Z,X and Y.

Current Output:

`Date      Building    Metric    Performance`
`--------------------------------------------`
`12/1/19      A         Z            1`
`12/1/19      A         Y            2`
`12/1/19      A         X            3`

Desired Output (functionally):
`12/1/19      A         W         =(1+2)/3`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that what you have shown is your question is table and what you want is some of the constants and aggregation of values.

Use `group by` with `aggregate function` as following:

```
Select date, building, 'W' as metric,
       Sum(case when metric in ('Y', 'Z') then performance end) 
      / sum(case when metric ='X' then performance end)
From your_table
Where metric in ('X','Y','Z')
Group by date, building
Having count(distinct metric) = 3
```

Also, handle the situation where `performance` against X is not 0 by adding condition on `sum` of X.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select date, building, 'W' as metric,
       (sum(case when metric in ('Z', 'Y') then performance end) /
        sum(case when metric in ('X' then performance end)
       )
from t
group by date, building;
```